# Share large object between internal thread-mappers of MultithreadedMapper class in Hadoop Mapreduce?

Tags: java, multithreading, hadoop

I have a simple **Hadoop job** in java with a mapper which processes my file line-by-line. Each mapper is NOT CPU-bound, but should hold a **very large object in memory** (a Bloom Filter in my case), which size is 2-15 Gigabytes (depends on computational accuracy). In Mapper's `setup()` method I read this object from disk and create it.

I came across `MultithreadedMapper` class to perform my calculations in multiple threads.

```
job.setMapperClass(MultithreadMapper.class);
// ...
MultithreadedMapper.setMapperClass(job, MySingleThreadMapper.class);
MultithreadedMapper.setNumberOfThreads(job, 16);
```

But it seems, that `MultithreadedMapper` uses internal `private class MapRunner extends Thread` to spawn thread-mappers:

```
public class MultithreadedMapper<K1, V1, K2, V2> extends Mapper<K1, V1, K2, V2> {
//...
    public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    // ...

        runners =  new ArrayList<MapRunner>(numberOfThreads);
        for(int i=0; i < numberOfThreads; ++i) {
            MapRunner thread = new MapRunner(context);
            thread.start();
            runners.add(i, thread);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the question: How can I create my very-very large object in MultithreadedMapper once and share it (using context or whatever) between thread-mappers at the cluster node (same jvm)?

I tried to make it through a Singleton pattern, but if seems to be not a beautiful solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preamble:** I've never done that before, but I would implement it using a static lock for initialization:

```
static class MySingleThreadMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

    static MyResource sharedResource;

    @Override
    protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        super.setup(context);
        synchronized (MySingleThreadMapper.class) {
             if (sharedResource == null) {
                 sharedResource = createResource();
             }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
       // mapper code
       // sharedResource will be initialized here
    }
}
```

As you may already know, Hadoop spawns its Map and Reduce tasks in separate JVM instances. So all your single thread mappers will run in the same JVM  and you can rely on a static lock. You can use any other static object as a lock, your shared resource will be initialized only once.